Update model field changes made in development branch to staging in Odoo
I am new to odoo.sh
I have made some changes, added few custom fields, in the product model. When trying to drag and drop to the staging branch it shows no new commits. But I have not done any code changes for adding the fields. Also I tried with git add . followed by git commit in the shell provided by them. First it shows error like not a git repository and the I navigated to some inner directory and finally made a commit. But then, that commit not showing anywhere else in my odoo.sh or my git account or anywhere.
Any help is appreciated,
thanks in advance.
I have tried many ways to update the staging version with the added fields and also some view changes. But it is not reflecting there.
I also tried with the db dump, unfortunately I can't get the dump from that odoo.sh development version.
